# Change the Solr Server URL on Drupal 7 from an external shell script

Tags: apache, drupal, solr, drupal-7

I have recently received a task of maintaining a Drupal site, with one of the tasks being writing a backup and import script for the dev site, so it can receive a daily dump of the live data.

I have done this, however we need to revert the Solr details to the dev solr database. However I only know how to do this manually using the UI tools (e.g. "https://WEBSITE.co.uk/admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings" clicking "edit" and changing the "Solr server URL" in the UI menu and clicking "Save" e.g. "https://WEBSITE/admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings/dev_environment_search_server__0_0/edit?destination=admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings").

Would there be a way of changing this without in a script?

Also updating the database table manually doesn't work unless you also clear the cache, is there a way of only clearing the Solr Cache for to update this change (I've been asked to not clear all caches)

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If Solr is setup using Search API you can add the [Search API Override](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_override) and [Search API Solr Override](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr_overrides) modules to allow you to control the configuration easily in your settings.local.php file.